# call recorder app is not recording outgoing call

Tags: android, mediarecorder, mediarecorder-api

I am working on an app "Call Recorder" I have given all permissions, but it's not recording incoming caller's voice. I am using MediaRecorder.

```
void startRecording() {
    final SharedPreferences shared = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    int[] ss = new int[]{
            MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL,
            MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION, // mic source VOIP
            MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION,
            MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER,
            MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, // mic
            MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT, // mic
            MediaRecorder.AudioSource.UNPROCESSED,
            MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_UPLINK,
            MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK,

    };
    int i = Integer.valueOf(shared.getString(CallApplication.PREFERENCE_SOURCE, "-1"));
    if (i == -1)
        i = 0;
    else
        i = Sound.indexOf(ss, i);

    String ext = shared.getString(CallApplication.PREFERENCE_ENCODING, "");
    if (Storage.isMediaRecorder(ext)) {
        startMediaRecorder(ext, ss, i);
    } else {
        startAudioRecorder(ss, i);
    }

    showNotificationAlarm(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
startAudioRecorder(ss, i);
```

put this line in if condition for record